# How to insert Comma-Separated Values in SELECT?

Tags: postgresql, pg-promise

Example:

```
const columns = ['circle', 'square', 'triangle']

db.any('SELECT ($1:csv) FROM table', [columns])
```

But, unfortunately, this option gives an error - ***operator does not exist: integer[] @> text[]***

Comment: You are trying to select values from a table instead of columns? That doesn't make sense. It is completely incorrect from SQL point of view.

Comment: @vitaly-t I'm trying to choose which columns are needed to form the result.

Comment: Are those actually column names? From the strings I would think they look like values :)

Comment: @vitaly-t Yes, I'm sorry, I mixed up the names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these are actually column names that you want to select:

```
const columns = ['circle', 'square', 'triangle'];
```

then the correct syntax is:

```
db.any('SELECT $1:name FROM table', [columns])
```

as per the [SQL Names](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#sql-names) documentation ;)